# Assign value to raster cells based on the nearest polygon value

Tags: raster, polygon, arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2

I have a polygonal layer of agricultural fields, with three possible Ecological values (a range of 1-3). Between the polygons, there are gaps with no polygons (due to dirt roads, water reservoirs and such). I need to fill these gaps with the same values the fields have, to turn the whole thing into a gapless polygonal layer.
To do this, I turned the gap area into a raster and now I want to assign each cell a value based on its nearest polygon. Any ideas on how to do this?

The next step would be to turn the raster layer back to a polygonal layer, and then merge the two polygon layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert [polygon data to raster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm), smallest cell size that is sensible for you, use your ecological values field.

[image: Polygons]

Rasterized polygons (1m resolution)

[image: Rasterized]

2. Run the [Distance Allocation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/distance-allocation.htm) tool, your input raster being your rasterized polygons. Set output name, other parameters can be ignored. Result is this:

[image: Result]

You don't need to merge anything as the source cell is included. Simply convert this raster back to a polygon format. Optionally smooth the polygon boundaries?

Comment: Thank, this worked great